# Как сделать иконку в heder квадратной или вообще без подьема?

Tags: java, android

Я использую библиотеку

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

и все вроде работает так как нужно, только проблема с иконкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она по умолчанию берется круглую форму...

Подскажите как можно сделать ее либо квадратной либо просто оставить как есть(без круга)

Comment: Просмотрев эту библиотеку думаю, что фича либы. Чем не устроил встроенный от гугл Navigation Drawer?

Comment: @Asgard у в нем можно повесить бейдж на `item`? Чтоб количество входящих писем показывало?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Конечно. Я, например, для navDrawer-a всегда делаю кастомный адаптер, хэдеры и футеры

Comment: @АндроидАндроид я сейчас тоже задумался про это  - подскажешь, где есть материалы насчет кастомного адаптера?Как раз сейчас в проекте было бы кстати. Думал, иначе нельзя.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да и я бы почитал... то что я находил и пробовал сделать, у меня так и не получилось нормально... Было б шикарно если есть какой то пример на гите рабчий

Comment: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/ Вот тут посмотрите в самом низу

Comment: @АндроидАндроид я читал этот туториал, но что то у меня не получилось там... не помню... А и ссылки там не работают, что сверху одна, что снизу которая на сам проект указывает...

Comment: ммм, не понял какие ссылки? там же исходники пошагово расписаны

Comment: @АндроидАндроид это да, но ссылка на сам проект не правильная, в самом низу как вы сказали. Я наверное еще раз попробую разобраться с этим туториалом.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko А, я просто ее не видел=)

Comment: Эммм, использовать View не из библиотеки, странный вопрос какой-то.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei мне просто не нравиться как сейчас выглядит логотип и мне кажется что это из за того, что он округляется...